# Execute Stored Procedure with XMl datatype in Entity model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

How to force Entity Framework to work with stored procedure with XML input parameter? Data is Updating Perfectly with Sql connection but I only have to use Entity framework

I have tried ExecuteFunction and ExecuteStoreQuery both are giving different Error as below

Both statements are giving Error

```
return base.ExecuteFunction<int>("pr_UpdateSupplierSubmittedExportdata_1", tblExportDataParameter, batchIDParameter, userNameParameter);
ex = {"The stored procedure or function 'pr_UpdateSupplierSubmittedExportdata_1' does not have a return type. ExecuteFunction only supports stored procedures and functions that have a return type. "}

 return base.ExecuteStoreQuery<int>("Exec pr_UpdateSupplierSubmittedExportdata_1 @tblExportData, @BatchID, @UserName ", tblExportData, batchID, userName);
Must declare the scalar variable "@tblExportData".


var getColumn = (from sp in (objLCSEntities.pr_UpdateSupplierSubmittedExportdata_1(xmlString1, Convert.ToInt32(sExportID), strUserFullName))
                                             select sp).First().ToString();
```

Stored Procedure Used:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [UpdateSupplierSubmittedExportdata_1]
    (
          @tblExportData XML,
          @BatchID INT,
          @UserName varchar(200)
          )
    AS
    BEGIN       
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
          --UPDATE EXISTING RECORDS
          -- import xml into temp table
          -- Creating Temporary Table
    CREATE TABLE #TEMP_TABLES
    (
        Updated_Accepted_Shipment_Date_EX_Works nvarchar(max),
        Updated_Invoice_Number nvarchar(max),
        Updated_Invoice_Date nvarchar(max),
        Updated_Handover_Date nvarchar(max),
        Updated_Revised_Delivery_Date_Ex_Works nvarchar(max),
        Updated_PO_Line_Progress nvarchar(max),
        Updated_Mode_of_Shipment nvarchar(max),
        Updated_Supplier_Remarks nvarchar(max),
        Updated_GSM_Remarks nvarchar(max),
        Updated_Weight int,
        Updated_Inspection_Offer_Date nvarchar(max),
        Updated_Development nvarchar(max),
        Updated_Transit_Qty int,
         Order_x0020_ID int

    );
    --      insert into @temp
    --select  T.c.value('@CustomerID', 'nchar(5)'),
    --        T.c.value('@ContactName', 'nvarchar(40)')
    --from    @XML.nodes('/ROOT/Customer') AS T(c)
    INSERT INTO 
    #TEMP_TABLES

    SELECT
    (x.c.value('Updated_Accepted_Shipment_Date_EX_Works[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')),--as Updated_Accepted_Shipment_Date_EX_Works,
    x.c.value('Updated_Invoice_Number[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'),-- as Updated_Invoice_Number,
    x.c.value('Updated_Invoice_Date[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'),--as Updated_Invoice_Date,
    x.c.value('Updated_Handover_Date[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'),-- as Updated_Handover_Date,
    x.c.value('Updated_Revised_Delivery_Date_Ex_Works[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'),--as Updated_Revised_Delivery_Date_Ex_Works,
    x.c.value('Updated_PO_Line_Progress[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'),--as Updated_PO_Line_Progress,
    x.c.value('Updated_Mode_of_Shipment[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'),--as Updated_Mode_of_Shipment,
    x.c.value('Updated_Supplier_Remarks[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'),--as Updated_Supplier_Remarks,
    x.c.value('Updated_GSM_Remarks[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'),--as Updated_GSM_Remarks,
    x.c.value('Updated_Weight[1]', 'int'),--as Updated_Weight,
    x.c.value('Updated_Inspection_Offer_Date[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'),--as Updated_Inspection_Offer_Date,
    x.c.value('Updated_Development[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), --as Updated_Development
    x.c.value('Updated_Transit_Qty[1]', 'int'), --as Updated_Development
    x.c.value('Order_x0020_ID[1]', 'int') --as Updated_Development
    FROM @tblExportData.nodes('/DocumentElement/MyTableName') as x(c)
    --select * from #TEMP_TABLE232
         --UPDATE EXISTING RECORDS
          UPDATE dbo.tblExportOrderdata
          SET Original_Ship_Dt = convert(datetime,c2.[Updated_Accepted_Shipment_Date_EX_Works])
          ,In_Transit_Qty = c2.[Updated_Transit_Qty]
          ,Invoice_No=c2.[Updated_Invoice_Number]
          ,Invoice_Date=c2.[Updated_Invoice_Date]
          ,Handover_Dt=c2.[Updated_Handover_Date]
          ,Rev_Delivery_Dt=c2.[Updated_Revised_Delivery_Date_Ex_Works]
          ,PO_line_progress=c2.[Updated_PO_Line_Progress]
          ,Mode_Of_Shipment=c2.[Updated_Mode_of_Shipment]
          --,GSM_Buyer_Remark=c2.[Updated_GSM Remarks]
          ,Supplier_Remark=c2.[Updated_Supplier_Remarks]
          ,Inspection_Offer_Date=c2.[Updated_Inspection_Offer_Date]
          ,weight=c2.[Updated_Weight]
          ,Development=c2.[Updated_Development]
          --,Status='Updated by Supplier'
          FROM dbo.tblExportOrderdata c1
          INNER JOIN #TEMP_TABLES c2
          ON c1.Order_Id = c2.Order_x0020_ID and c1.Batch_ID=@BatchID
      DROP table #TEMP_TABLES  


           IF  EXISTS
    (select 1 from [LCS_QA].[dbo].[tblExportInbox]
     where Batch_No=@BatchID AND Status='Submitted To Supplier' )
    --and Fls_Site_Name IN (SELECT * FROM DBO.CSVTOTABLE(@FlsSiteName))
    --and Country IN (SELECT * FROM DBO.CSVTOTABLE(@Country))) --

    BEGIN  
    UPDATE [LCS_QA].[dbo].[tblExportInbox] SET Status='Updated By Supplier' , Updated_Date=getdate() , Updated_By=@UserName
    WHERE Batch_No=@BatchID --AND Status='Submitted To Supplier'

    END
     DECLARE @ResultValue int
     SET @ResultValue=-1
     select @ResultValue
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

EF is built on top of ADO.NET, and you can always access the underlying DbConnection from a DbContext to use ADO.NET directly.

For EF6 the pattern is:

```
        using (var db = new MyDb())
        {
            var con = (SqlConnection) db.Database.Connection;
            con.Open();
            var cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            //...

        }
```

For EF Core:

```
    using (var db = new Db())
    {
        db.Database.OpenConnection();
        var con = (SqlConnection)db.Database.GetDbConnection();
        var cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        //...
    }
```